# Is there any way in Swift 2.0 to make extension methods optional to implement?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm developing a framework in Swift 2.0 that adds a few extension methods to `NSManagedObjectContext`. These methods are useful but not required for use of the framework. I'd like users of my framework to be able to opt in to the use of these extension methods, perhaps by implementing a protocol. However, when I provide a default implementation, I want to be sure that `self` is always `NSManagedObjectContext`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people are now aware that Swift 2.0 can specialize extension methods around generic parameters, e.g.,

```
extension Array where T: Int {
  // This method only appears when T is an Int
  func seven() -> Int {
    return 7
  }
}
```

It's also possible to constrain `Self` in this way, and this is what makes "opt-in" extension methods possible. The key here is `where Self: NSManagedObjectContext` in the extension below:

```
public protocol ManagedObjectContextType {
    func from<E: EntityType>(_: E.Type) -> EntityQuery<E>
    func newEntity<E: NSManagedObject where E: EntityType>(_: E.Type) -> E
    func newEntity<E: NSManagedObject where E: EntityType>() -> E
}

/**
Extend `NSManagedObjectContext` with this interface in your project to
benefit from these methods.
*/
extension ManagedObjectContextType where Self: NSManagedObjectContext {
    /**
    Initiates a query whose result type is `E`.
    */
    public func from<E: EntityType>(_: E.Type) -> EntityQuery<E> {
        return EntityQuery(builder: QueryBuilder()).context(self)
    }

    /**
    Inserts a newly allocated entity of type `E` into this `NSManagedObjectContext`.
    */
    public func newEntity<E: NSManagedObject where E: EntityType>(_: E.Type) -> E {
        return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(E.entityNameInManagedObjectModel(persistentStoreCoordinator!.managedObjectModel), inManagedObjectContext: self) as! E
    }

    /**
    Inserts a newly allocated entity of type `E` into this `NSManagedObjectContext`.
    */
    public func newEntity<E: NSManagedObject where E: EntityType>() -> E {
        return newEntity(E)
    }
}
```

The beauty of this is that the Swift 2.0 compiler recognizes in these extensions that `self` is an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`, so you can use all of the appropriate methods.

Now, users of your framework can decide for themselves whether they want to add your extension methods by simply implementing the interface in their project:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext: ManagedObjectContextType {}
```

This allows authors of frameworks to provide extensions and default implementations in a less cluttered way.

Comment: *"What most are not aware of ... "* – any sources for that claim ? :)

Comment: Yes, the lack of any mention of it I could find on SO when I was trying to figure out how to do this, though perhaps my search skills are not up to par.

Comment: It is of course possible that everyone is aware of it and it's not worth mentioning. If so, my apologies. :)

Comment: It looks like an interesting application of protocol extensions. *I* would just try to avoid subjective statements like that. Don't take my comment too serious!

Comment: I never take anything too seriously, but I did edit out the subjective claim. I think it's probably still valid, but it doesn't add anything to the answer and removing it certainly doesn't subtract anything. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: This technique does not seem to work with value types.